# Show OpenLayers bounds after creating a circle

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, polygon, vector-graphics

I have made an OpenLayers map.

I have made two features on the map.

- Navigate
- Draw Polygon

I have made 40 sides to my polygon which turns out to be a circle. After I have drawn my circle I want to show the coordinates of the bounding box of the circle. So after I draw a circle I want to be able show the top, left, bottom and right coordinates for that circle in an ALERT BOX?

My code is attached and below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map {
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    #controls {
        width: 512px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 1em;
        left: 1em;
        width: 512px;
        z-index: 20000;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    }
    #controlToggle {
        padding-left: 1em;
    }
    #controlToggle li {
        list-style: none;
    }
</style>

<script src="js/firebug.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var lon = 24.0000000000; 
var lat = -29.000000000000;

var zoom = 4;
var map, layer, vectors, controls;

function init(){
    // Because the Streetmaps system uses 300x300 tiles, we need to set up the scaling variables to work with these
    var aRes =     [90,45,22.500000,11.250000,5.625000,2.812500,1.406250,0.703125,0.351563,0.175781,0.087891,0.043945,       0.021973,0.010986,0.005493,0.002747,0.001373,0.000687,0.000343];
    for (var l=0;l<aRes.length;l++) { 
        aRes[l] = aRes[l]/300; 
    }

    // Normal init, but we pass through the info about the zoom/scaling as options
    map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map', 
    { 
        tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(300, 300), 
        projection: 'CRS:84', 
        numZoomLevels: aRes.length, 
        resolutions:aRes, 
        maxResolution:360/300 
    });

    // At this point the control is used as per normal            
    layer1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
        'Streetmaps Streets',
        'http://www.streetmaps.co.za/WMS/?',
        {
            key:                                    'HZPGNWPNDYPREPTIKSIHWKYKQYYOQVYX',
            service:                                'WMS',
            request:                                'GetMap',
            version:                                '1.3.0',
            layers:                                 'sm.maps.tiled',
            format:                                 'image/png'
        }
    );

    layer2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
        'Streetmaps Imagery',
        'http://www.streetmaps.co.za/WMS/?', 
        {
            key:                                    'HZPGNWPNDYPREPTIKSIHWKYKQYYOQVYX',
            service:                                'WMS',
            request:                                'GetMap',
            version:                                '1.3.0',
            layers:                                 'sm.imagery',
            format:                                 'image/png'
        }
    );

    // This loads the map
    map.addLayer(layer1);
    map.addLayer(layer2);

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
    map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher() );
    var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vector", {isBaseLayer: true});
    map.addLayers([vectors]);

    // This loads the overlays
    var wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", 
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'}); 

    var polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer");

    map.addLayers([wmsLayer, polygonLayer]);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

    polyOptions = {sides: 40};
    polygonControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygonLayer,
        OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon,
        {handlerOptions: polyOptions});

    map.addControl(polygonControl);          

    document.getElementById('noneToggle').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('irregularToggle').checked = false;
}

function setOptions(options) {
    polygonControl.handler.setOptions(options);
}

function toggleControl(element) {
    for(key in controls) {
        var control = controls[key];
        if(element.value == key && element.checked) {
            control.activate();
        } else {
            control.deactivate();
        }
    }
}

   </script>
   </head>
   <body onLoad="init()">
<div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
    <div id="controls">
        <ul id="controlToggle">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="type"
                    value="none" id="noneToggle"
                    onclick="polygonControl.deactivate()"
                    checked="checked" />
                <label for="noneToggle">navigate</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="type"
                    value="polygon" id="polygonToggle"
                    onclick="polygonControl.activate()" />
                <label for="polygonToggle">draw polygon</label>
            </li>
        </ul>          
    </div>
      </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not in any sense an OpenLayers expert, and will be glad to be corrected by readers who actually know something about OpenLayers, but ...

When you're creating your DrawFeature control, if you replace

```
{handlerOptions: polyOptions}
```

with

```
{handlerOptions: polyOptions, featureAdded: noteAdded}
```

and define `noteAdded` along these lines

```
function noteAdded(f) {
  alert(f.geometry.getBounds());
}
```

then you will get exactly the notification you're asking for. In general, what gets passed to the function specified by `featureAdded` is a feature object; in this case it's an `OpenLayers.Feature.Vector` whose `geometry` property contains all the information about your polygon.